What would happen if I did not set up %block TBT.HS.Files correctly?
I have calculated the SCF solution of a certain system at 21 different applied bias from 0.0 to 2.0 at steps of 0.1 eV.
However, when I set up block TBT.HS.Files, I mistakenly included only the first 6 files.
%block TBT.HS.Files
../V0.0/siesta.TSHS  0.0 eV
../V0.1/siesta.TSHS  0.1 eV
../V0.2/siesta.TSHS  0.2 eV
../V0.3/siesta.TSHS  0.3 eV
../V0.4/siesta.TSHS  0.4 eV
../V0.5/siesta.TSHS  0.5 eV
%endblock

I ran tbtrans using the following scripts:
#!/bin/bash
for V in $(seq 0.0 0.1 2.05) ; do
   d=TBT_${V//,/.}
   mkdir $d
   cd $d
   mpirun --map-by ppr:18:node -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 tbtrans -V "${V//,/.}:eV" ../TS.fdf > TBT.out
   cd ../
done

I found tbtrans is working well and did not warn me about anything. It even is calculating the interpolated transmissions and currents at 1.1V, far from the largest voltage../V0.5/siesta.TSHS  0.5 eV I set up.
What is happening now?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

The TBT.HS.Files block is used to read the provided files, and extrapolate a Hamiltonian only for the provided files.
So, by omitting some, you are doing a worse interpolation.
Please note, that this is an interpolation and care should be taken that sometimes (especially when the bias introduces new bands) can create non-physical results.
When you are calculating the transport for an exact TranSiesta calculation, then I would highly recommend you to not use TBT.HS.Files. The block should only be used if you want to interpolate the Hamiltonian.

It's really great to hear this, Sir.
